# Integral inequality in $L^p(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set and $u\in L^p(\Omega)$, with $p>1$. Let $\Omega_1 = \left\lbrace x\in\Omega\mid u(x) >k\right\rbrace$ where $k$ denotes a positive constant greater than 1. It is always true that
$$\int_{\Omega_{1}} \vert u\vert^p dx >1?$$

Any hints to prove (or not!) that it is true?

Thank You!

Comment: Would you like the inequality in the other way around? Because if we let $k$ going to infinity, the integral goes to $0$ hence $\int_{\Omega_{k}} \vert u\vert^p dx >1$ with $\Omega_k = \left\lbrace x\in\Omega\mid u(x) >k\right\rbrace$ cannot hold.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean that the inequality holds true with "<" instead of ">"?

Comment: I mean that it is more likely to be true. But it seems that there can be counter-examples for both: if $\lvert u\rvert\leq k/2$ almost everywhere, then $\Omega_1$ is empty. If $u=2k\mathbf 1_A$, then $\Omega_1=A$ and $\int_{\Omega_{1}} \vert u\vert^p dx=(2k)^p\lambda(A)$ which can be bigger or smaller than one according to the measure of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

One easily finds counterexamples trivial counterexamples: $u=0\in L^p$

But there are also quite easy non-trivial counterexamples, e.g. using characteristic functions of "small enough" sets or functions bounded by $1$.